# Write the division and the remainder on two variables using php

Tags: php

I am dividing 1779 by 30. I want to write the answer (without the remainder) to one variable and write the remainder to another variable.

How do i get this?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number without remainder:

```
$result = (int) (1779 / 30);
```

The remainder:

```
$result = 1779 % 30;
```